# Add a link to each image

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, slideshow

Can anyone spare 5 minutes to help me with something that is driving me crazy!

I am *not* a developer and I am trying to use this slideshow in my personal website. 
http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/

I'd like to add a link to each of the images (the link will open a new website on a separate window).
But adding a simple

```
<a href="..."><img src="img/recent01.jpg" /></a>
```

doesn't work and it messes up the slideshow :/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Instead of wrap the `<img>` with an `<a>` tag, which might mass up with the css rules, just bind an onclick event to the `<img>` tag, like:

```
<img src="img/recent01.jpg" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com')" />
```